# Collapsible button inside a ul list does work in jsfiddle but not in WP

Tags: css, javascript

I implemented a collapsible button, it works well in WP, but if I insert it in a `ul` list it doesn't work, that is the button does not open.

Then I tried to run the code in jsfiddle and there it does work.

The only difference between the WP code and the jsfiddle code is in the javascript

- on WP the `var content` is defined by `this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;`
- on jsfiddle the `var content` is defined by `this.nextElementSibling;`

This is due to the fact that

- by removing `parentElement` on WP the button will break
- by adding `parentElement` on jsfiddle the button will break

Just for information, the javascript on WP is loaded in the footer.

Is it possibile to fix the problem? Here is the [jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/Ascalon/ev5djrhq/1/).

---

Below you can see jsfiddle vs WP

[image][image]

---

### HTML FROM CHROME INSPECT TOOL

```
<div class="entry-content">
        <p>Does <button class="col">this</button> work?</p>
<div class="con space" style="">
<p>Yes!</p>
<p></p></div>
<hr>
<ul>
<li>Does <button class="col">this</button> work?
<div class="con space">
<p>Only in jsfiddle, not in WP!</p>
</div>
</li>
<li style="">another line</li>
</ul>
    </div>
```

### HTML FROM WP CLASSIC EDITOR

```
Does <button class=col>this</button> work?
<div class="con space"><p>Yes!<p/></div>

<hr>

<ul>
  <li>Does <button class=col>this</button> work?
      <div class="con space"><p>Only in jsfiddle, not in WP!</p></div></li>
  <li>another line</li>
</ul>
```

The `space` class just contains `margin-bottom: 1.5em;`

Comment: Is the WP output slightly different?  If parentElement is necessary, it sounds like there must be some extra markup when it's output.  Any chance we could see the exact HTML from WP (not from the template file, but what is being output to the screen)?

Comment: The spacing in the output is slightly different because I have customized the ul spacing in the `style.css` and other minor things. Now I post the HTML I get from the chrome inspector, is this what you meant? About the JS, another user suggested me to turn the JS into an IIFE cose, but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the update. WP is inserting `<p>` tags, which are causing the problem. I copied your code from JSFiddle to a WP install, and without adding `parentElement` it worked perfectly, as long as I manually removed the paragraph tags that were automatically added by the WP editor.  If those paragraph tags are in there, the `.col` and `.con` elements are no longer siblings, which is why it breaks.

Comment: Oh yes you found the problem thank you! So what you suggest to do? Is it better that I keep the `parentElement` and manually add <p> tags when the button doesn't work?

Comment: Or you could do something like this to accommodate both:
`var content = this.nextElementSibling;
 if (!content) {
 content = this.parentElement.nextElementSibling;
 }`

Comment: Wow thank you very much! You saved me! If you want add the answer so I can give you the points you deserve :)

Comment: There is another small problem, since somehwere in the text I have equations placed as images `<img src...>`, if there are equations between `.col` and `.con` then the button doesn't work.

Comment: This is nasty, but I'm brain dead: `coll = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
conn = document.getElementsByClassName("con");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
 coll[i].setAttribute('data-id', 'con' + i);
 conn[i].setAttribute('id', 'con' + i);
  coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
  var content = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('data-id'));
    if (content.style.maxHeight) {
      content.style.maxHeight = null;
    } else {
      content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
    }
  });
}`

Comment: Holy cow man this is amazing!! It solves all the problems!! Thank you very much you legend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution provided by Steven

```
<script type="text/javascript">
( function() {
    coll = document.getElementsByClassName("col");
    conn = document.getElementsByClassName("con");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < coll.length; i++) {
        coll[i].setAttribute('data-id', 'con' + i);
        conn[i].setAttribute('id', 'con' + i);
        coll[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
            this.classList.toggle("active");
            var content = document.getElementById(this.getAttribute('data-id'));
            if (content.style.maxHeight) {
                content.style.maxHeight = null;
            } else {
                content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
            }
        });
    }
} )();
</script>
```